# Mac OS. Finder windows split the screen?

Tags: macos, finder

I want to achieve something like this at least for 4 windows:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Checkout [Divvy](http://mizage.com/divvy/). It snaps windows to various parts of the screen.

Also, checkout [Total Finder](http://totalfinder.binaryage.com/). It is a finder replacement that gives you split screens.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a native "snap" fucntion similar to the feature in Windows 7 and Winodws 8.

You will unfortunately have to manually lay out the windows on your desktop that way or download a special program that may do the trick.

Take a gander: http://lifehacker.com/5809879/how-to-get-windows-best-features-on-mac-os-x

Answer (score 1):

I found Better touch tool a while ago which has many improvements that work seamlessly. It also pretty much has the features you're looking for in that you can drag windows to the side for half screen, or to corners for quarter screen windows. It won't split a window into four at once, but you can create your own four windows and then drag them to the corners to achieve the same effect:
http://www.boastr.net/